# geting multipal checkMark whenever i use didselect method in tableview than its show two check mark ,at a time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want implement checkMark in tableView cell but when I select cell then Automatically two checkMark show in cell.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        //tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    }
}
```

this is my code

Comment: Can you show an image that one cell containing two checkmarks?

Comment: select one cell for check  mark but two cell show check mark

Comment: You mean two cell**s** are checked in one action? I mean, when no cell is selected, just a single touch on any of the cells causes all cells selected ?

Comment: yes , two check mark show in two cell , when press one cell , means one action

Comment: Then you should better update your question to clarify. Though, I cannot reproduce the same issue. You may be doing something wrong in your hidden code.